# Character sums over a sumset

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, analytic-number-theory, character-sums

Suppose that $p$ is a prime, $A$ is a subset of $\mathbb F_p$, and $P$ is a polynomial over $\mathbb F_p$ of degree $d$. Using Weil's bound, it is not difficult to show that
  $$ \left| \sum_{a,b\in A} \left(\frac{P(a+b)}{p}\right)\right| \le d|A|\sqrt{p} $$
(where $(\cdot/p)$ is the Legendre symbol).

> Are better estimates known?

In case it helps, the polynomial $P$ can be assumed to split completely into linear factors.

I am aware of the [Friedlander-Iwaniec "Estimates for character sums"](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1993-119-02/S0002-9939-1993-1152276-X/S0002-9939-1993-1152276-X.pdf), but they consider the particular case $P(x)=x$ only, and impose some rather restrictive assumptions on $A$. (On the other hand, they study the asymmetric case $a\in A$, $b\in B$, and allow *any* character instead of the Legendre symbol.)

Comment: Not exactly what you are looking for but see Chang's work on the Davenport-Lewis Problem and character sums in finite fields, such as: http://math.ucr.edu/~mcc/paper/DubProc.pdf as well as the recent work on convolutions of multiplicative characters such as: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1134/S0081543817010217 and https://arxiv.org/pdf/1509.04354.pdf